# How to detect the fundamental frequency in a signal using wavelets?

Tags: wavelet

I have a noisy sine signal from which I want to extract the fundamental frequency of the sine. What should I use?

The signal is in the discrete time domain with a known sampling frequency. Actually I am trying to corroborate the answer I got by an FFT analysis so I cannot use a FFT.

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Which domain, continuous time or discrete? In either case, is your objective to obtain the best estimate or to use wavelets regardless of outcome quality? For instance, a homework pb. Without further details, the Fourier transform is all you need.

Comment: The wavelet scale that best matches the underlying sine wave will have the maximum projection. Moreover, the projection amplitude (envelope) will be independent of translation. So look for the maximum projection amplitude that is also least effected by translation (the translation will be periodic, but the min/max envelope will be constant).

Comment: Any idea how I can do this in a MATLAB environment?

Comment: Take a look at my solution in R below and use `cwt()` function in MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of `R` code which implements continuous wavelet transform on some signal (using the `biwavelet` package).

The signal is composed of a sine wave with frequency 40 Hz and random noise.
The result is a spectrum showing that the frequency 40 Hz dominates in the whole signal.

```
signal.len <- 1024  # input param.
sin.freq   <- 40    # input param.

# noise + 40 Hz sine wave
signal <- rnorm(signal.len) + sin(sin.freq*2*pi/signal.len * 1:signal.len)

library(biwavelet) 
w <- wt(cbind(index(signal), signal))  # continuous wavelet transform

# rendering the results
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot.default(signal, type = "l", xaxs = "i")  # the signal
plot.biwavelet(w, useRaster = TRUE)           # spectrum of the signal
```

[image]